# JavaScript compare two arrays and push items to the first array that have the same property value in the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and want to push the values from the second array having the same property value. Comparing the values by using `addrSeq` property and push the matching object in to `vpainfo` array

Below are the sample JSON structure,

**Array1**:

```
[
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "accountMask": "********7479",
    "vpainfo": []
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "accountMask": "********74",
    "vpainfo": []
  }
]
```

**Array2:**

```
[
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "saasasa@fff"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "xyz@com"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "vpa": "saas@ddd"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please also include the expected output. Do you need `Array1` to be updated?

Comment: What is the expected output? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to learn javascript, here is result please look into this i just store both into array, and then run loop and match and push into one.

```
    let firstarray =[
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "accountMask": "********7479",
    "vpainfo": []
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "accountMask": "********74",
    "vpainfo": []
  }
]

let secondarray = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "saasasa@fff"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "xyz@com"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "vpa": "saas@ddd"
  }
]
// merge both array into one using addrSeq match value 
let mergedarray = firstarray.map(function(item) {
    secondarray.map(function(item2) {
        if (item.addrSeq == item2.addrSeq) {
            item.vpainfo.push(item2);
        }
    });
  return item;
});

console.log(mergedarray);
```

Comment: Thanks. But one object got missed from second array and `addrSeq` having two objects. after pushing it showing only one object

Comment: please look now working fine  i update that

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it via simple `forEach` loop.

**Demo :**

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "accountMask": "********7479",
    "vpainfo": []
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "accountMask": "********74",
    "vpainfo": []
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "saasasa@fff"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "xyz@com"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "vpa": "saas@ddd"
  }
];

array2.forEach((obj) => {
    array1.forEach((array1Obj) => {
    if (obj.addrSeq === array1Obj.addrSeq) {
        array1Obj.vpainfo.push(obj.vpa)
    }
  });
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, But want the values inside `vpainfo` as array of multiple objects with key and value pairs. can you please help on this?

Comment: you want to push whole object instead of only `vpa` value ? If Yes, then you can use `array1Obj.vpainfo.push(obj)` instead of `array1Obj.vpainfo.push(obj.vpa)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OP requires **`Array1`** to be updated such that each object's `vpaIinfo` array gets updated based on the data in **`Array2`**, the following solution may be one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getUpdatedArr = (ar1, ar2) => (
  ar1.map(
    obj => ({
      ...obj,
      vpainfo: [
        ...obj.vpainfo,
        ...ar2.filter(
          ({addrSeq}) => (obj.addrSeq === addrSeq)
        ).map(
          ({vpa}) => vpa
        )
      ]
    })
  )
);

const arr1 = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "accountMask": "********7479",
    "vpainfo": []
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "accountMask": "********74",
    "vpainfo": []
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "saasasa@fff"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "12",
    "vpa": "xyz@com"
  },
  {
    "addrSeq": "13",
    "vpa": "saas@ddd"
  }
];

console.log(getUpdatedArr(arr1, arr2));
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over array-1 using `.map()`
- For each object, keep the rest of the props as-is & manipulate only `vpainfo`
- Retain any existing values in current `vpainfo` (using `...obj.vpainfo`)
- Append to this, any relevant `vpa` found in array-2
- The above is accomplished by using `.filter()` to retain only those with same `addrSeq` -AND- then, using `.map()` to extract just the `vpa` prop (using de-structuring)

Comment: This may be used like so: `let newArray1 = getUpdatedArr(array1, array2);` as the method does not mutate `array1`. If one needs array1 to be updated, then instead of `newArray1` simply using `array1` should work.

Comment: jsNoob, Thanks. But want the array of objects with key and value pairs in `vpainfo`. can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

- Loop through first array
- Find the matching items from second array by comparing the `addrSeq` values.
- Update the `vpainfo` of item in first array as the concatenated value of `vpa`s from second array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arr1 = [
    { "addrSeq": "12", "accountMask": "********7479", "vpainfo": [] },
    { "addrSeq": "13", "accountMask": "********74", "vpainfo": [] }
]
const arr2 = [
    { "addrSeq": "12", "vpa": "saasasa@fff" },
    { "addrSeq": "12", "vpa": "xyz@com" },
    { "addrSeq": "13", "vpa": "saas@ddd" }
]
arr1.forEach((node) => node.vpainfo = node.vpainfo.concat(arr2.filter(item => item.addrSeq === node.addrSeq).map(item => item.vpa)))
console.log(arr1);
```